# Javascript - trying to copy an array whtout loosing refrence

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a select element (delivery time) that needs to update when changing another select element (delivey say).
In my HTML/PHP i ha three hidden select hours elements for each day option.
in this javascript I have an event listener for change in delivery day.

Array.prototype.push.apply(t, t3); copies the element but deletes t3 (so if a user rechooses the day it's empty.

t = [...t3];  Copies the element without deleting t3 but cuts the refrence to document.getElementById("shipping_time").options so i get an empty selector

````
//update hours
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  const selectElement = document.querySelector('#shipping_day');

  selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    var selectedday = document.getElementById("shipping_day");
    var t = document.getElementById("shipping_time").options;
    var t1 = document.getElementById("shipping_time1").options;
    var t2 = document.getElementById("shipping_time2").options;
    var t3 = document.getElementById("shipping_time3").options;
    var i;

    if(selectedday.options.selectedIndex==0){
      t.options=0;
      Array.prototype.push.apply(t, t1);
    }
    if(selectedday.options.selectedIndex==1){
      t.length=0;
      Array.prototype.push.apply(t, t2);
    }
    if(selectedday.options.selectedIndex==2){

      t.length=0;
      //Array.prototype.push.apply(t, t3);
      //t = [...t3];

    }

  console.log(t);
  console.log(t1);
  console.log(t2);
  console.log(t3);
  console.log(document.getElementById("shipping_time"));

  });
});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that a DOM node cannot be in two places at the same time, so you're actually **moving** them. If you absolutely need to use hidden fields as source for your select options, then you have to clone the options in order to **copy** them somewhere else in the DOM:

```
Array.from(t1).map(x => x.cloneNode(true)).forEach(x => t.add(x));
```

Here is a working demo:

```js
const [mainSelect, abcSelect, defSelect, firstButton, secondButton] = ['main-select', 'abc-select', 'def-select', 'first-button', 'second-button'].map(document.getElementById.bind(document));

firstButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Array.from(abcSelect.options).map(x => x.cloneNode(true)).forEach(x => mainSelect.options.add(x));
});
secondButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Array.from(defSelect.options).map(x => x.cloneNode(true)).forEach(x => mainSelect.options.add(x));
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="main-select">
</select>

<select id="abc-select" class="hidden">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>

<select id="def-select" class="hidden">
  <option>d</option>
  <option>e</option>
  <option>f</option>
</select>

<button id="first-button">Add abc</button>
<button id="second-button">Add def</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. one note, it's t1, not t1 options